# How does one retrieve records with all days in date range covered?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014, where-clause

Imagine you have something like a action rental or hotel scenario where a unit can have rates for specific days and they can be available or not. I want to be able to search all my units for a specified arrival date and departure date to only bring back units that meet the whole time period.

Lets say each unit has a rate table similar to below

```
PropertyID    Rate    Start_Date    End_Date   Status    Type
1             400     03/12/18      03/13/18   Available Daily
1             400     03/13/18      03/14/18   Available Daily
1             400     03/14/18      03/15/18   Available Daily
1             400     03/15/18      03/16/18   Reserved  Daily
1             400     03/16/18      03/17/18   Available Daily
1             400     03/17/18      03/18/18   Available Daily
1             400     03/18/18      03/19/18   Available Daily
1             900     03/12/18      03/19/18   Blocked   Weekly
```

Daily rates are split into each day due to the fact you can book a day at any time while a weekly rate needs the full range available. In the above case, it turns out that I would NOT be able to rent the weekly rate as the 15 day is reserved and that is part of the weekly rate.

If someone were to search that they wanted to stay 3/12/18 to 3/19/18 and assuming all of the above was available, I have it it doing in a store procedure (pseudo code)

```
Select stuff
From Property
Inner Join PropertyRate pr
where pr.Start_Date = @arrrivalDate And pr.End_Date = @departureDate
```

This would get me the property back because the weekly rate fits. However if the weekly rate was removed and it was only the daily rates, this would not return this property. Assuming all the statuses were available for the daily rates, **this property should return because each day of the period specified is available.**

How can I check if each day in the requested date range has an available date for that time period?

If it matters, this is Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

**Edit 1:**

It was requested for table definitions. Here is the property rate table create script:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[PropertyRates]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PropertyRates](
    [property_rate_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [rate_details_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [property_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [rate] [money] NOT NULL,
    [start_date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [end_date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [status] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [created] [datetime] NOT NULL,  
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PropertyRates] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [property_rate_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

I believe that is what was asked.

**Edit 2:**

I wasn't very clear on what I'm trying to do for an output. Since this SQL is used in a search function, I only want to return the SINGLE property record for the property if it has available rates on every day of the passed in search range. So the end SQL should just have the property record if the many rates for that property are available and cover every day in the passed in date range.

Also note, that besides daily and weekly rates, there are also other such as monthly, bi-monthly, daily 2 day min, etc but they all have the start and end date columns filled in.

So for the above example, for a stay from 3/12 to 3/19, I should NOT get the property back because there is no range of days covered by available because the weekly rate is blocked and the daily rate has a reserved in the middle. If the reserved rate changed to available, the property should be returned.

Comment: Can you provide table definitions? You have some sample data but no idea how you would query this because there are no details about the tables.

Comment: @SeanLange I added something which I believe is what you are asking for. If not, let me know.

Comment: That helps but I don't understand the output. Why should the weekly rate be returned? There is a reservation for one of the days during that period. I don't understand very clearly what you want as output.

Comment: @SeanLange Updated question again. Hopefully that makes it a bit more clear. The rates table has many rates per property but for my search SQL I just want to return the property only if the rates are available for the whole period passed in.

Comment: So in your example you should get nothing returned? That property is not available for all dates in the date range. Unless it is ok to find the weekly rate for the time period when one of the days is already reserved. To be honest I think the biggest challenge here is the data structure is less than ideal. You have overlapping dates for that property with different rates and one of the dates is reserved, wouldn't that mean the weekly rate is unavailable?

Comment: I was just editing the question again to add that lol. Yes, for my example you would get NOT get this property back because all the days in the range are not available. For your question "You have overlapping dates for that property with different rates and one of the dates is reserved, wouldn't that mean the weekly rate is unavailable?", yes the weekly rate is unavailable due to the reserved date in the center, so in the database it's status is "blocked" meaning it can't be used but no actual reservation was made on that rate. The only status I should be looking at is available for the search

Answer (score 0):

```
select propertyid,count(*) 
from property 
where count(*) = datediff(dd,@startenddate, @enddate)+1 
and status='Available'
    group by propertyid
```

This will calculate the number of days requested (datediff) and calculate if there are that number of days in the table that are available.

Comment: This looks like it is a good start of something but I think it it's focusing on daily rates only? I updated my question so it may help better explain what I'm looking for. I added the output I'm expecting.

Answer (score 0):

`UNION ALL` could be a good way to handle this:

```
DECLARE @ArrivalDate Date = '20180312'
DECLARE @DepartureDate Date = '20180319'

SELECT *
FROM myTable t1
JOIN (SELECT PropertyID, Type --Handle Weekly Availability
      FROM myTable
      WHERE Type = 'Weekly'
      AND Status = 'Available'
      AND Start_Date = @ArrivalDate
      AND End_Date = @DepartureDate
         UNION ALL
      SELECT PropertyID, Type --Handle Daily Availability
      FROM myTable
      WHERE Type = 'Daily'
      AND Status = 'Available'
      AND Start_Date >= @ArrivalDate
      AND End_Date <= @DepartureDate
      GROUP BY PropertyID, Type
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Start_Date) = DATEDIFF(Day, @ArrivalDate, @DepartureDate)
    ) t2 ON t1.PropertyID = t2.PropertyID --JOIN back to retrieve other needed data
        AND t1.Type = t2.Type
```

[Fiddle example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2fadb/6/0)

Note, I changed the sample data to have one valid daily and one valid weekly example.

Comment: Reading the SQL I think this should do what I want but I'm wondering if it is possible a little more generically? Besides daily and weekly there are items such as monthly, bi weekly, daily 2 day min, etc but the common thread is they all have a start and end date which I'm trying to see if every day in the passed in range is covered by a start and end date from the rates table.

Comment: Hmm.. If you could blow out every case to look like daily by joining to a date table, you could probably get the bottom "Daily" portion of my query to work for all types.  I'll see if I have time to try it later.

Comment: Thank you. I'll poke around at it a bit as well. In the mean time, I updated my question, not sure if that makes anything clearer.